# Why do functions from event queue aren't called even when main executions stack is empty?

Tags: javascript, eventqueue

I was reading an article on event queue.

And the authour say " *funcitons from event queue aren't executed until they find the main execution stack empty* "

and to demonstrate the same he provide the following example

```js
function documentClickHandler() {
  console.log('CLICK!!!');
}

document.addEventListener('click', documentClickHandler);

function a() {
  const fiveSecondsLater = new Date().getTime() + 5000;
  while (new Date().getTime() < fiveSecondsLater) {}
}

a();
```

```html
Click here!
```

So, in this case, the `documentClickHandler` goes into the event queue. and the function `documentClickHandler` will not be executed unitil main **execution stack is empty** . In this case until the function `a` finishes its work the *documentClickHandler* will not be executed . right !.

**But that's not working the way it is indented to .....**
i think it doesn't even listens to clicks and is that due to heavy work done by function `a`.

i) Can you provide me any other example that explains the same, the example that can prove that event queue functions aren't executed until the execution stack is empty ?

ii) Why the example is not working! I have clicked the window at the time when function *a* is executing and the documentClickHandler doesn't even show it work when funciton *a* has done its work !

Comment: Your example works: while `a` executes, no click events are handled, but as soon as it finishes, all pending events are handled and click handler starts working as usual.

Comment: Agree. The example works fine. What kind of browser do you use?
It seems answer for the first question is not needed)

Comment: i am using chrome

Comment: if I want to execute this example in nodejs env , How ill i do this , i think i have to use fetch API

Comment: Can you add link to the article looks like a misconception